# Laravel Routing from subdirectory HTTP Request back to root

Tags: php, http, routes, laravel

In my routes.php file, I want to click content in an a tag which will send an http request in the form of an href string when clicked and routes.php will route to a destination if a route is specified. The problem I'm having is that when I am at mywebsite.com/view1/view2 and I send the http request 'view1', routes.php tries to send view1/view1. How do I get the http request to start from the root directory every time its called no matter how many directories deep the request is being made from?

```
Route::get('view1', function()
{
return View::make ('view1.nav')
});


Route::get('view1/view2', function()
{
return View::make ('view2.nav')
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to say without seeing the views, but be sure you're linking to your routes properly `<a href="{{ URL::to('view1') }}">` should generate the proper URL.  There's some more advanced information on generating links [here](http://jasonlewis.me/article/laravel-reverse-routing)